# Android Webview youtube video open full screen

Tags: android, video, webview, youtube, fullscreen

I am developing an android app.This app has a webview. It contains several youtube iframes. When I click the video, it is opened in the webview. But I want to open the video in new full screen or native video player.

This is code snippet

```
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        mWebChromeClient = new myWebChromeClient();
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://m.youtube.com");
```

But When I open m.youtube.com from chrome and when I click any video, The video is being opened in new video screen. How can I do the same like chrome.
I have been googled and read all other problem in stackoverflow.com I haven't get any successfull result.

Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: Did u find a solution

Comment: Any Solution @nebyan

Comment: I have no solution :(